# Mapping an array inside an object in React with ES6

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, lodash

I'm making a react-feed app, inspired by [Michael's tutorial](https://github.com/michaelcheng429/react-tutorial-todos) (there's also [a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IR6smI_YJDE)) and I encountered some trouble trying to pass an array inside an array as props using [Lodash's _.map](https://lodash.com/docs#map) function. This is the information I'm mapping:

```
const events = [ 
                {
                    event: 'Gods',
                    venue: 'Asgard',
                    venuePicture: 'picture1.jpg',
                    when: '21:00 27/04/16',
                    genres: ['rock', 'funk'],
                    artists: [
                        {
                            artist: 'Thor',
                            artistPicture: 'thor.jpg'
                        },

                        {
                            artist: 'Loki',
                            artistPicture: 'loki.jpg'
                        }
                    ]

                },

                {
                    event: 'Humans',
                    venue: 'Midgard',
                    venuePicture: 'picture2.jpg',
                    when: '21:00 27/04/16',
                    genres: ['jazz', 'pop'],
                    artists: [
                        {
                            artist: 'Human1',
                            artistPicture: 'human1.jpg'
                        },

                        {
                            artist: 'Human2',
                            artistPicture: 'human2.jpg'
                        }
                    ]

                }


             ];
```

I'm passing to the component like this (this works):

```
renderItems(){
        const props = _.omit(this.props, 'events');

        return _.map(this.props.events, (event, index) => <EventsFeedItem key={index} {...event} {...props}/>);

    }

    render() {
            return (
                <section>
                    {this.renderItems()}
                </section>
            );
        }
```

This works perfectly fine, dividing each "event" object [image: (here's a screenshot of it working)]

Then I try to destructure and map the "artists:" object of each event like this:

```
renderArtists() {

        const { event, venue, venuePicture, when, genres, artists } = this.props.events;

        const props = _.omit(this.props, 'events');
        return  _.map({artists}, (artist, index) => <ItemArtist key={index} {...artist} {...props}/>);

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ul>
                {this.renderArtists()}
            </ul>
        );
    }
```

This is the result I'm getting, which is close, but not what I need:[image]

I need to separate these further to get:

```
{artist: "Thor"} {artistPicture: "thor.jpg"}
{artist: "Loki"} {artistPicture: "loki.jpg"}
```

and so on...

I see there's a pattern here, I just don't know how to implement it further. It breaks when I try to repeat the same destructure then _.map thing. Can anyone please give me a hand with this, sorry for the long post.

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Array"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: what about using `_.get`? I think it will serve purpose, also could you uplod this to jsbin or some good place where we could test this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return _(this.props.events).flatMap('artists').map((artist, index)=><ItemArtist key={index} {...artist} {...props}/>).value();
```

Comment: Your first comment (the one you deleted) solved my problem VyvIT, thanks a lot! I can't believed I spent all this time and I didn't notice it :D

Comment: No problem, here's a solution to flatMap the artists from the initial events array.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I found the problem thanks to [VyvIT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/175954/vyvit)'s comment (he deleted his comment), it's here:

```
const { event, venue, venuePicture, when, genres, artists } = this.props.events;
    _.map({artists}, (artist, index) => <ItemArtist key={index} {...artist} {...props}/>);
```

"artists" shouldn't be destructured (curly brackets), should be like this:

```
_.map(artists, (artist, index) => <ItemArtist key={index} {...artist} {...props}/>);
```

Thank you so much guys!